# obscure bug while using ti.draggable

Tags: android, mobile, titanium, drag

This is a simple code of Appcelerator Titanium Mobile application it works almost fine, but...

```
var drag = require('ti.draggable');

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({exitOnClose: true, backgroundColor: 'black', navBarHidden: true});

var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({
    left: 0,
    width: '50%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#9966cc'
});

win.add(view1);

var dragView = drag.createView({
    backgroundColor: '#99cc33',
    left: 50, top: 50,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    zIndex: 5    
});

dragView.addEventListener('start', function(e){
    var p = {x: e.source.left, y: e.source.top};
    var tp = e.source.parent.convertPointToView(p, win);
    e.source.parent.remove(e.source);
    e.source.left = tp.x;
    e.source.top = tp.y;
    win.add(e.source);
});

dragView.addEventListener('end', function(e){
    var p = {x: e.left, y: e.top};
    var tp = win.convertPointToView(p, view2); 

    if(tp.x < 0){
        tp = win.convertPointToView(p, view1);
        e.source.parent.remove(e.source);
        e.source.left = tp.x;
        e.source.top = tp.y;
        view1.add(e.source);    
    }else{
        e.source.parent.remove(e.source);
        e.source.left = tp.x;
        e.source.top = tp.y;
        view2.add(e.source);    
    }
});

view1.add(dragView);

var view2 = Ti.UI.createView({
    left: '50%',
    width: '50%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#cc6699'
});

win.add(view2);

win.open();
```

If my dragView was draged over to view2 from view1, and dragView.left = 100, dragView.top = 100, then when i try to drag it again it jumps to same coordinates on win. why is that?

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I have found out that this is not a bug. Reason is that on "end" event you change the coordinates and the parent of the view. And this is fine since the view stops moving. The problem is on "start". You remove the view from the parent and reattach it somewhere else, this works fine. What does not work, is the resetting of the coordinates, since inside of the source code, they are constantly being changed and changes made in the JS after the fact do not affect it at all until the finger has lift up the screen

The reason I built this module is to make draggable views smooth in Titanium, but it can easily be implemented in JS.

You should consider one of two options; build it all in JS, or use the maxLeft, minLeft, minTop, maxTop, properties to stop the view from moving "outside" of another, but attach the view to the window.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for you answer. I've manage to made it without using your module. Here is the source code:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    exitOnClose: true,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    navBarHidden: true  
});

var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({
    left: 0,
    width: '50%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#9966cc'
});

win.add(view1);

var dragView = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: '#99cc33',
    left: 50, top: 50,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    zIndex: 5,
    startDragx: 0,
    startSragy: 0,
    dragCoef: 0    
});

dragView.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    var p = {x: e.source.left, y: e.source.top};
    var tp = e.source.parent.convertPointToView(p, win);

    e.source.dragCoef = 0;

    e.source.parent.remove(e.source);
    e.source.left = tp.x;
    e.source.top = tp.y;
    win.add(e.source);

    e.source.startDragx = e.x;
    e.source.startDragy = e.y;
});

dragView.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
    if ((++e.source.dragCoef % 2) == 0){
        e.source.left += e.x - e.source.startDragx;
        e.source.top += e.y - e.source.startDragy;
        e.source.startDragx = e.x;
        e.source.startDragy = e.y;
        e.source.dragCoef = 0;
    }
});

dragView.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    var p = {x: e.source.left, y: e.source.top};
    var tp = win.convertPointToView(p, view2); 

    if(tp.x < 0){
        tp = win.convertPointToView(p, view1);
        e.source.parent.remove(e.source);
        e.source.left = tp.x;
        e.source.top = tp.y;
        view1.add(e.source);    
    }else{
        e.source.parent.remove(e.source);
        e.source.left = tp.x;
        e.source.top = tp.y;
        view2.add(e.source);    
    }
});

var view2 = Ti.UI.createView({
    left: '50%',
    width: '50%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#cc6699'
});

view2.add(dragView);

win.add(view2);

win.open();
```

But 'touchend' event does not occur. I've tried to add event listeners to win, not to dragView, but it's same story, 'touchend' event never fired up. Where is the problem? I launch it only on android emulator.

Comment: moreover, if i just touch my dragView and than lift up my finger(without trying to move it), 'touchstart' event will works fine and 'touchend' event works fine, but if i'll try to move dragView 'touchend' event doesn't works.